# does CEPH RBD mount on Linux support boot device?

Tags: ceph

Does CEPH RBD mount on Linux support boot device?

for RBD deployment, example would be like this:
http://blog.programster.org/ceph-deploy-and-mount-a-block-device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on what you mean as a boot device.  There are three possible meanings for that term depending on who you talk to:

1. The device the bootloader is loaded from.
2. The device the bootloader loads the kernel from.
3. The device that holds the root filesystem.

In the first case, you need firmware support, not OS support (you may want special OS support though, but that's not strictly required), and I can say with relative certainty that there is currently no OEM firmware that supports booting via RBD.

In the second case, you need support from the bootloader, which as far as I know, is not present in any standard Linux bootloader (GRUB 2 is the only one I can think of that might have it, but I know that the upstream version of GRUB 2 does not have such support).

Only in the third case is it a question of OS support, and the answer there is that while the kernel itself does not directly support booting with root on RBD, it is possible (in theory at least) to do so with an initramfs.